# Computing $\iint_B(x^2+2y^2-3z^2 )\,dS$ over unit sphere $B\subset\mathbb R^3$

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

Let $B$ be the unite sphere in $R^3$. Then what is the value of

$$\iint_B(x^2+2y^2-3z^2 )\,dS$$

over the surface $B$ ?

I substituted the value of $z^2$ as $1-x^2-y^2$ and then integrated the resulting function over the projection $x^2+y^2=1$.

Was I wrong in doing this?

Comment: Did you use the surface area integral formula?  Of did you only replace $dS$ with $dx\,dy$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^2+y^2\leq 1$?

Comment: I'm not sure, could you show me the solution so that i can point my mistake out?

Comment: I pointed a mistake out, above. The projection is the set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$. Otherwise, with an equality instead you would constrain $z$ to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you decide to compute the integral, here's one way using the surface integral formulation so you can compare your solution.

$$\iint_B(x^2+2y^2-3z^2)\,\mathrm dS$$

Parameterize $B$ by the vector-valued function,

$$\mathbf s(u,v)=\langle\cos u\sin v,\sin u\sin v,\cos v\rangle$$

with $0\le u\le2\pi$ and $0\le v\le\pi$. Then

$$\mathrm dS=\left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf s}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf s}{\partial v}\right\|\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=\sin v\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

The integral then becomes

$$\int_{v=0}^{v=\pi}\int_{u=0}^{u=2\pi}(\cos^2u\sin^2v+2\sin^2u\sin^2v-3\cos^2v)\sin v\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=0$$

Comment: Just a note for clarity: this parameterization is based on the conversion from rectangular to spherical coordinates, with the sphere radius equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "integrating over the projection", but here are some facts to consider:

1.$\;\iint(x^2+2y^2-3z^2 )\,dS = \iint x^2\,dS + 2\iint y^2\,dS-3\iint z^2\,dS$

2. $\iint y^2\,dS$ and $\iint z^2\,dS$ over $B$ are equal to $\iint x^2\,dS$ over a suitable rotation of $B$ (different rotations for the two integrals).
3. Spheres are invariant under rotation.
4. When you see an integral in math class that looks really complicated, there's about a 10% chance the answer is zero.

Comment: I assume that integrating over the projection means integrating, over the disk $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand how surface integrals of $y^2$ and $z^2$ over B are equal to that of $x^2$ ?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes the projection meant $x^2+y^2≤1$ with respect to x and y!